# Norse-based fantasy show where protagonist can use every ability?

Tags: story-identification, tv, magic, animation

I'm looking for an animated series (100% not an anime) taking place in a fantasy world that might have had a Nordic aesthetic, where everyone had a unique superpower. (i.e. wings, ice manipulation, ect). The basic premise is that the protagonist, the adopted or blood son of a blacksmith, finds a legendary stone through which he becomes able to use any power. However this stone is also coveted by the villain, who wears a mask and has wings and two swords (could be either/or with the wings and swords). I am quite certain this aired before 2016